# Azure pipelinne issue - none.js version

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

so I'm a little new to Azure and am trying to deploy a pipeline on azure devops from a github repo.
When i try to do this, the job fails at the npm install and build stage, because 'Node.js version v10.24.1 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v14.20, v16.13 or v18.10.'

I've checked the version of node on my machine and its v18, however during the job, during the install node.js step, I think its using an old version of node. However I'm unsure how to change this. Log for none.js installation on azure:
Install Node.js

View raw log

## Starting: Install Node.js

## Task         : Node.js tool installer
Description  : Finds or downloads and caches the specified version spec of Node.js and adds it to the PATH
Version      : 0.218.0
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js

Downloading: https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.24.1/node-v10.24.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
Extracting archive
/usr/bin/tar xC /home/vsts/work/_temp/03b1dcb9-eb8c-4670-a1e8-005b1a301667 -f /home/vsts/work/_temp/f4579837-7ffe-4b90-885d-a007e659aa26
Caching tool: node 10.24.1 x64
Prepending PATH environment variable with directory: /opt/hostedtoolcache/node/10.24.1/x64/bin
Finishing: Install Node.js

I'll inside some screenshots below for more context:
[image: install node.js - azure pipeline]

[image: Npm install and build error]

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the NodeTool@0 step to use a version spec.

Assuming you're building the pipeline with UI rather than a yml file it looks like this in the pipeline step configuration:

[image]

If you are using a .yml file, it looks like this:

```
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSource: 'spec'
    versionSpec: '16.16.0'
```

Obviously you're free to choose whatever supported version of Node you'd like.

Comment: Thank you for the comment! I've fixed this but now am getting this error:

Run `npm audit` for details.
Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.6) is greater than your local version (15.0.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

Comment: Try upgrading the angular cli in your package.json to match the one on the build server